# Controlsaligned and controls is not working in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, animate

I'm trying to use `controlsaligned` and only show the `play,stop,step` buttons in controllers. Here there is the code that I'm using

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \definecolor{lava}{rgb}{0.81, 0.06, 0.13}
    \definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.30, 0.60}
    \usepackage{gensymb}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes}
    \usepgflibrary{shapes.symbols}
    \usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees,arrows,shapes.symbols,shapes.misc}
    \usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
    \usepackage{lmodern}  
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
    \usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{animate}  
   \newcounter{angle}
\setcounter{angle}{0}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{animateinline}[loop, poster = first,controls={[play,stop,speed]},controlsaligned=right+-4em]
\whiledo{\theangle<359}{
\vspace{-1em}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]    
    % Axis
    \draw[thick,->,black] (-3,0)--(3,0) node[below] {$\Re$}; % x axis
    \draw[thick,->,black] (0,-3)--(0,3) node[left] {$\Im$}; % y axis
    \draw[black,thick] (0,0) circle (2.5cm);
    \node[black,below] at (2.6,0) {$V_m$};
    \node[black,above] at (0.1,-2.5) {$V_m$};
    %
    \draw[ultra thick,lava] (0,0) -- (0,0 |- \theangle:2.5cm); % UpOn x axis
    \draw[ultra thick,myblue] (0,0) -- (\theangle:2.5cm |- 0,0); % UpOn y axis
    %
    \draw[densely dotted,lava] (\theangle:2.5cm) -- (\theangle:2.5cm |- 0,0); % vertical line
    \draw[densely dotted,myblue] (\theangle:2.5cm) -- (0,0 |- \theangle:2.5cm); % horizontal line
    \draw[ultra thick,black,->,rotate=\theangle] (0,0) -- (2.5,0); 
    \node[red,myblue,right] at (0,-3.1) 
            {\footnotesize$\cos(\theangle^{\degree}) = \pgfmathcos{\theangle}\pgfmathresult$};
    \node[lava,lava,right] at (0,-3.5) 
            {\footnotesize$\sin(\theangle^{\degree}) = \pgfmathsin{\theangle}\pgfmathresult$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    %
    \stepcounter{angle}
    \ifthenelse{\theangle<359}{
            \newframe
    }{
    
            \end{animateinline}
    }
}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The error is

> ​! Missing number, treated as zero.

Comment: Please help us to test your code! Extend your code snipped to small but complete document which reproduce your problem.

Comment: code is included

Answer (score 2):

There are some syntactic errors in the code: The `[` and `]` around `play,stop,speed` are wrong and the framerate argument is missing in the `animateinline` environment.

Also, the code uses a `\whiledo` loop around parameterized frames which is deprecated practice. Use `\multiframe` instead.

To prevent the running animation from wiggling, an invisible node is placed into the `tikzpicture` to push its right bounding box edge a bit. This ensures that all frames have the same size.

Note that negative dimensions used with `controlsaligned` cause the controls to protrude outside the animation widget. Not sure if this is your intent. (I removed it in the code below.)

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage{lmodern}  
\definecolor{lava}{rgb}{0.81, 0.06, 0.13}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.30, 0.60}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{animate}   
    
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{animateinline}[loop, poster = first,controls={play,stop,speed},controlsaligned=right]{30}
  \multiframe{360}{iAngle=0+1}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
    \node at (3.9,0) {}; % push right bounding box border somewhat 
    % Axis
    \draw[thick,->] (-3,0) -- (3,0) node[right] {$\Re$}; % x axis
    \draw[thick,->] (0,-3)--(0,3) node[left] {$\Im$}; % y axis
    \draw[black,thick] (0,0) circle (2.5cm);
    \node[black,below] at (2.6,0) {$V_m$};
    \node[black,above] at (0.1,-2.5) {$V_m$};
    %
    \draw[ultra thick,lava] (0,0) -- (0,0 |- \iAngle:2.5cm); % UpOn x axis
    \draw[ultra thick,myblue] (0,0) -- (\iAngle:2.5cm |- 0,0); % UpOn y axis
    %
    \draw[densely dotted,lava] (\iAngle:2.5cm) -- (\iAngle:2.5cm |- 0,0); % vertical line
    \draw[densely dotted,myblue] (\iAngle:2.5cm) -- (0,0 |- \iAngle:2.5cm); % horizontal line
    \draw[ultra thick,black,->,rotate=\iAngle] (0,0) -- (2.5,0);
    \node[red,myblue,right] at (0,-3.1)
            {\footnotesize$\cos(\iAngle^{\degree}) = \pgfmathcos{\iAngle}\pgfmathresult$};
    \node[lava,lava,right] at (0,-3.5)
            {\footnotesize$\sin(\iAngle^{\degree}) = \pgfmathsin{\iAngle}\pgfmathresult$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\end{animateinline}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: when I run this code I get the error ( Package ifthen Error: You can only set a boolean to `true' or `false'.)

Comment: @Diana Not at my end. Are your packages up to date?

Comment: How can I get them up to date, I usually use usepackage{} and they are downloaded

Comment: @Diana MiKTeX? If I remember correctly, you have to open "MiKTeX console" from the MiKTeX section in the Start menu. In the MiKTeX console click something like "Search for updates" or so.

Comment: it looks like I have a problem since I can't find MiKTeX Console in Mac

Comment: Which kind of TeX distribution are you using (MacTeX, TeXLive)? MiKTeX is Windows only.

Comment: I have found FixMacTeX2014.pkg and setup-2015.pkg in my Application-Tex folder, I guess this means I have MacTeX

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112904/discussion-between-alexg-and-diana).

Comment: Works fine (+1)! Small suggestion: that animation will not trembles, increase x axis, for example `\draw[thick,->] (-3,0) -- (3.2,0) node[right] {$\Re$}; % x axis
`

Comment: @Zarko I noticed the trembling too and I was pondering how to find out the largest horiz. extension of the `tikzpicture` caused by the numbers and insert a fixed bounding box. I'll incorporate your suggestion. Thank you!